# Python Pandas and SciPy: Optimal method to identify point and compute moving vector

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy

I have created pandas dataframe with point positions at time (some t0, t1, ..., tn) with structure shown below. I`ve tried to indentify point and compute moving vector for each. Unfornetly, iterating over every point is relative slowly. What is the most efficient method to predict points position in the future (in tn+1, tn+2, ...)? I want to know concept, not code. It's part of system predicticting thunderstorm cluster moving. I used, amoung others, Pandas and SciPy algorithms.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsUhe.png)

Comment: Could you show the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, of course. I send df as new attachment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial answer for your question. You have to do a multivariate time series analysiswhich should include statistical testing of your model. From here on there are plenty of models that you can choose: regression models, SARIMA models, diffusion models, LSTM models, etc. Usually the appropriate choice can be made with cross-validation and similar methods.

I'd recommend researching the topic before jumping into coding, because it's a fairly complicated one. However, this question should not be discussed at stackoverflow.